# The getter isn't defined for the type <dynamics>

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to learn Flutter and Dart for an upcoming project.. I have experience with Java and PHP but this is very new for me.. Help me out pls..

Getting error at line 53 and 56 in the code attached below where I have included stream.streamURL and stream.streamName .

main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'streamData.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
          home: firstCard(),
        ));
    
    class firstCard extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<firstCard> createState() => _firstCardState();
    }
    
    class _firstCardState extends State<firstCard> {
      List<Streams> streamData = [
        Streams(streamName: "vishwesh", streamURL: "vishwesh.io"),
        Streams(streamName: "vxshwxsh", streamURL: "vxshwxsh.io")
      ];
    
      Widget streamTemplate(stream) {
        return StreamCard(stream: stream);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('First Card'),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: streamData.map((result) => streamTemplate(result)).toList(),
            ));
      }
    }
    
    class StreamCard extends StatelessWidget {
      final Stream? stream;
    
      StreamCard({this.stream});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(stream?.streamURL,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.grey[600])),
                  SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                  Text(stream.streamName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey[800]))
                ],
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

streamData.dart

```
class Streams {
  String? streamName;
  String? streamURL;

  Streams({required this.streamName, required this.streamURL});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I think the error is due to a typo in your code:

```
class StreamCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream? stream;
```

You declared a variable of type Stream in StreamCard class, rename it to Streams instead.The final code would be:

```
class StreamCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Streams? stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `final Stream? stream;` to `final Streams? stream;`. You were not using the class that you created on a different file, instead you used an abstract class from Dart itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a stupid mistake also the null safety feature is makes it more difficult